# Poor internet speeds

Tags: internet, speed

I have an internet connection which the providers said that I will get 20 MBPS speed and minimum 10 MBPS it means I will have to get minimum 500 kbps download speed, but I am getting only 250-300 kilo bytes per second. why ?
as my speed test is also shows 10.00 MBPS/14.20/21.46mbps, but I am getting only 230kbps. I closed all the programs and only running down-loader app on windows 7.
why this so?

Comment: I am paying for 20 mbps speed but getting only 300 kbps speed

Comment: who is your provider ?

Comment: Please rephrase and clarify - starting by using a better title! How is 'minimum 10MBps' even closely related to 500kbps? Why does one follow from the other? (Also note the difference between b bits and B bytes.) Where are you downloading from? Is it from all download locations? And so on.

Comment: I have a nominal 17Mb/s connection, but have never seen much better than 700MB/s, or less than half the nominal speed. I am geographically distant from my local exchange, so I don't consider this too unreasonable. [This site](http://www.speedtest.net/) reports up to 6Mb/s, which is consistent with 700MB/s. Note my use of b(its) and B(ytes).

Comment: Be grateful some are only averaging 50-100 KB/s...

Answer (score 1):

If your speed test shows full speed but downloads from elsewhere don't, your tester must be testing against something closer to your provider's network, and your download is probably from a far network which might be slower then your provider's network.
Congratulations, your internet speed is better than average in your region.